# In Split, should one cross out 200

Tags: house-rules, split

On the Split scorecard, the last box in each row is worth 200 points. The rules say that in scoring you should cross off the next available box, but don't go out of their way to point out that a 6th pair is very bad or a 40th negative is very good because either your positive score for pairs or negative score for penalties would drop to 0.

My interpretation has been that 200 is intended to be the maximum score or penalty and that additional marks are just ignored rather than cancelling everything, but I'm wondering if this is the intended or commonly used ruling.

Comment: Which game called Split are you talking about? [Split (1966) by Western Publishing Company](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/24545/split), [Split (1999) by GDC-GameDevCo Ltd](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/186/split), or [Split (Revised Edition, 2001) by Hasbro](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/5332/split-revised-edition)?

Comment: It's the Hasbro one. I didn't even realize there were others :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The last two are apparently two versions of the same game, but the Revised Edition has a completely different goal, so I guess it's up to the individual of how true that is.